# Multiple AND OR inside a powershell if statment

Tags: 2013, powershell, cmdlets

I am trying to write a PowerShell script for my SharePoint 2013. The idea is that I what to select all the links that are referencing `/documents/` folder, and that ends with either `.doc` `.docx` or `.pdf`. in other words I want all the links that are referencing `/documents/` folder and that are either `Word` or `PDF`. so I wrote the following If statement :-

```
 $links = $file.ForwardLinks;
    foreach($link in $links){ 
        if($link.url -like '*/Documents/*' -and ($link.url -like '.doc' -or $link.url -like '.docx'  -or $link.url -like '.pdf') ){
```

But this will not select any links. Although there are link that contain both `/documents/` & `.pdf`.

Can anyone advice on this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't you need to make this: `($link.url -like '.doc' -or $link.url -like '.docx'  -or $link.url -like '.pdf')`

like this:

```
($link.url -like '*.doc' -or $link.url -like '*.docx'  -or $link.url -like '*.pdf')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the same using

```
$ext = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($link.url)
if($ext -eq '.doc' or $ext -eq '.docx' or $ext -eq '.pdf')
{
   #file found
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `*` in all the file extension tests